# How to edit address that is in container and add to storage seperately in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a container that displays default address of the customer, when I click edit I will be editing the address when it is done it should add to the storage as different variables like doornumber, streetname, city, state.
Below code I have added address in the Text, when I click edit it should be editable and make changes to respective variables.

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
          child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 380,
              child: Card(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.location_on),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 6,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                            '${appdata.doorNumber} ${appdata.landmark} ${appdata.streetname} ${appdata.city} ${appdata.State}'),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                        onPressed: () {
                         
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  )))),
```

Comment: please add your address model and the way you use it

Comment: how do you present edit page?

Comment: I need to edit in that container only.